# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 MaxstSDK

Tags: ios, swift

When adding the SDK i get this compile error

ld: warning: ignoring file /Path/To/Project/MaxstVideoFramework.framework/MaxstVideoFramework, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Path/To/Project/MaxstVideoFramework.framework/MaxstVideoFramework (2 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MasCameraDevice", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ScanForCouponsViewController.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using swift.

Does any have an idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably your project supports more architectures or more iOS versions than the SDK. You will have to decrease yours or increment the ones supported by the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try in this terminal this code:

```
lipo -info /path/to/your/framework/binaryfile
```

Maybe the framework doesn't support architecture x86_64.

Also you should read the SDK documents, maybe you missed some settings just like "Other linker Flags".

Comment: the limo command returns
Architectures in the fat file: MaxstARSDKFramework.framework/MaxstARSDKFramework are: armv7 arm64

Comment: I am new to Xcode , the valid architecture in my project setting are arm64 armv7 and armv7s , which one do I remove ? and if I remove one of them does that mean that my app will not run on a specific device ??
thanks in andvance

Comment: You shouldn't remove any of them. That framework needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: @user3336078  Well,actually the framework doesn't support architecture x86_64.Try to run your app project on a device, not on simulator.

Comment: @user3336078 Also you can find a new version of the framework , or find another framework in similar, if you wanna run on simulator.